# How to mix string with variables in an input needing mutiple values in js? (In this case, the coord attribute of the area tag)

Tags: javascript, html, area, coords

So what the problem I have been facing so far is that I am currently trying to use javascript so that the coords attribute of my area tag is set according to some variables(what it is doesn't really matter). However, the coords require 4 inputs (x1,y1,x2,y2) and I have some values that I am not going to use the variable for. Which means that I have to mix string and variables in the input which I have no idea on how to do.

To give you a better sense on what I am doing, here is a summary:

```
var p = some random value
var q = some random value

var a1 = document.getElementById(areaID);
a1.setAttribute("coords", "0,0, p,q")
```

Of course this didn't work as the "" made it think that p,q are strings instead of variables. So I tried some other where it all failed(some desperate attempts).

```
a1.setAttribute("coords", 0,0,p,q);
a1.setAttribute("coords", "0,0," + p + "," + q);
document.getElementById(areaID).coords = 0,0, p,q;

const list = ["0","0", p,q];
a1.setAttribute("coords", list);
```

So does anyone know how could I possibly do this?

Answer (score 1):

The second option you tried should work. In your example, is `areaID` a variable or the actual id of the element?  If it is the latter, then you need to put it in quotes: `document.getElementById("areaID")`

```js
var p = "val1"
var q = 23

var a1 = document.getElementById("areaID");
a1.setAttribute("coords", "0,0," + p + "," + q)

console.log(a1);
```

```html
<div id="areaID"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the "" as the areaID is meant to be the id. However, in my actual program I checked and the "" is included.